# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol for class unordered_map

Tags: c++, unordered-map, lnk2019

My code works on my school computer when using Visual Studio, but as soon as I tried on my computer with Visual Studio 2012 too, it compiles but gives me this error when I build my project :

> Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::unordered_map,class std::allocator >,int,struct std::hash,class std::allocator > >,struct std::equal_to,class std::allocator > >,class std::allocator,class std::allocator > const ,int> > > __cdecl getFrequency(class std::vector,class std::allocator >,class std::allocator,class std::allocator > > >,class std::unordered_map,class std::allocator >,int,struct std::hash,class std::allocator > >,struct std::equal_to,class std::allocator > >,class std::allocator,class std::allocator > const ,int> > >)" (?getFrequency@@YA?AV?$unordered_map@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@HU?$hash@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@U?$equal_to@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@std@@@2@@std@@V?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@2@V12@@Z) referenced in function _main
>   C:\Users\name.lastname\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects[Cpp]Mapping\Debug[Cpp]Mapping.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Since it works on my school computer with the exact same code, Im not giving you the code because it is very heavy. I think it the problem is that the linker cannot see the unordered_map class, I know how to add library to my project but not this specific class.
Any ideas?

Comment if you really think that the code is important.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Here is my Map_Operations.h file where I declare the getFrequency(); method :

```
#ifndef MAP_OPERATIONS_H_
#define MAP_OPERATIONS_H_

#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

std::unordered_map <std::string, int> getFrequency(std::vector<std::string> FILE_CONTENT, std::unordered_map<std::string, int> MASTER_MAP);

#endif /* MAP_OPERATIONS_H_ */
```

And here is the file Map_Operations.cpp where I implement it:

```
#include "Map_Operations.h"

#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

unordered_map <string, int> getFrequency(vector<string> FILE_CONTENT, unordered_map<string, int> & MASTER_MAP){

unordered_map <string, int> MAP;

// Iterate through the current file being copied and push_back all the words in the
// DOCUMENTS_ALL vector and in the MAP to compute their frequency
for(vector<string>::size_type j = 0; j != FILE_CONTENT.size(); ++j){

    string TEMP = FILE_CONTENT[j];

    unordered_map<string, int>::const_iterator MAP_CURRENT = MAP.find(TEMP); // Create iterator to know if the Key is in the MAP or not
    unordered_map<string, int>::const_iterator MAP_MASTER  = MASTER_MAP.find(TEMP); // Create iterator to know if the Key is in the MAP or not

    if ( MAP_CURRENT == MAP.end() ){ // If not in the MAP add it without incrementing
        MAP[TEMP] = 1;
    }else{ // If it is in the MAP then increment and add it
        MAP[TEMP] = MAP[TEMP]+1;          
    }

    if( MAP_MASTER == MASTER_MAP.end()){ // If not in the MASTER_MAP then add it
        MASTER_MAP[TEMP] = 1;
    }else { // If already in it then increment counter
        MASTER_MAP[TEMP] = MASTER_MAP[TEMP]+1; 
    }
}

return MAP;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with `unordered_map`, the problem is with `getFrequency`.

You must link with the library providing that function.

Comment: Thanks for replying. What do you mean by link with the library providing that function?

Comment: Your project (or one of your projects's dependencies) is calling a function named `getFrequency`, which is implemented by an external library, that's the library you must link with.

Comment: Well, I have a file Main.cpp where I include "Map_Operations.h" and I've implemented "Map_Operations.cpp" where there is the function getFrequency(); 
How do i link that then?

Comment: ok, edit your post and add the following information: Declaration and definition of the function `getFrequency` and, confirm if `Map_operations.cpp` **belong** to the project (and is compiled). btw, did you try a quick rebuild?

Comment: I found the issue.. But it's really weird and I dont know why.. In my getFrequency, i pass an unordered_map by reference, but when I removed it, it compiled and ran perfectly.. And it's because when i declared it I didnt put the & sign so it was as if it wasnt declared! Thanks anyway :)